# React TypeError: Cannot read property 'nbaGames' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Says the nbaGames is undefined on line 7. I've done this before with other examples but this is giving me a problem. getNbaGames is never even called before the error is thrown. I'm using https://github.com/bradtraversy/devconnector_2.0/tree/master/client as the foundation of this. Thanks

NbaGames.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import NbaGameItem from './NbaGameItem';
import { getNbaGames } from '../../actions/game';

const NbaGames = ({ getNbaGames, nbaGame: { nbaGames } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getNbaGames();
  }, [getNbaGames]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      
      <div className="posts">
        {nbaGames.map((nbaGame) => (
          <NbaGameItem key={nbaGame._id} nbaGames={nbaGame} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

NbaGames.propTypes = {
  getNbaGames: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  nbaGame: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  nbaGame: state.nbaGame
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getNbaGames })(NbaGames);
```

game.js (reducer)

```
import {
  GET_NBA_GAMES,
  GAME_ERROR,
  GET_NBA_GAME,
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  nbaGames: [],
  nbaGame: null,
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};

function gameReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_NBA_GAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        nbaGames: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case GET_NBA_GAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        nbaGame: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    
    case GAME_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default gameReducer;
```

game.js (action)

```
import api from '../utils/api';
import { setAlert } from './alert';
import {
  GET_NBA_GAMES,
  GAME_ERROR,
  GET_NBA_GAME,
} from './types';

// Get posts
export const getNbaGames = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await api.get('/posts');

    dispatch({
      type: GET_NBA_GAMES,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: GAME_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};

// Get post
export const getNbaGame = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await api.get(`/posts/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_NBA_GAME,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: GAME_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your function definition:

```
const NbaGames = ({ getNbaGames, nbaGame: { nbaGames } }) => {
```

The first time the component is rendered, the `nbaGame` prop will be `null` according to your default state (I'm not sure why your error message says it's `undefined` instead of `null`, potentially because no action has been dispatched yet, so the reducer hasn't even initialized the default state). This means that the destructured argument `nbaGames` cannot be accessed, because `nbaGame.nbaGames` is not valid if `nbaGame` is `null`.

I'm a bit confused about what the structure of your `nbaGame` and `nbaGames` objects is supposed to be, so I cannot say what the right solution would be, but generally speaking the problem could be solved in a few different ways:

- Make the default value of `nbaGame` `undefined` instead of `null` and then use a default argument in the component definition: `const NbaGames = ({ getNbaGames, nbaGame: { nbaGames } = { undefined } }) => {`
- Change the default value of `nbaGame` to be an object
- Change the component definition to not destructure the argument: `const NbaGames = ({ getNbaGames, nbaGame }) => {`. Then access `nbaGames` using the optional chaining operator (`nbaGame?.nbaGames`).

Answer (score 0):

In my index.js reducer file I have game as the state variable, so in

```
mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  nbaGame: state.nbaGame
});
```

it needs to be state.game

index.js (reducer) below

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import alert from './alert';
import auth from './auth';
import profile from './profile';
import game from './game';
import post from './post';

export default combineReducers({
  alert,
  auth,
  profile,
  game,
  post
});
```